# What is the official etymology of the term "service" module?

Tags: apollo-program, terminology

**Are there any reputable sources about how the word "service" was chosen for the Apollo *service* module?**

(This is a question about *how the term was chosen*, not about *what the term means*.  Surprisingly, it appears this question has not been asked here before.)